# Error running Logman.exe while creating trace

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a new trace using logman.exe with a provider on Powershell:

```
logman create trace TestTrace -rt -p {4027c655-f257-47ed-90f5-ecd6d2959e60} -ets
```

It gives me following error:

> Argument 'p' requires additional parameters.
>   Argument 'encodedCommand' is unknown.
>   Argument'NgAwADIANwBjADYANQA1AC0AZgAyADUANwAtADQANwBlAGQALQA5ADEAZgA1AC0AZABjAGQANgBkADIAOQA1ADkAZQA2ADAA' is unknown.
>   Argument 'inputFormat' is unknown.
>   Argument 'xml' is unknown.
>   Argument 'outputFormat' is unknown.
>   Argument 'text' is unknown.

If anyone has faced a similar problem. Please respond. Thanks.

Comment: I think its because powershell sees the content in the curly braces as an expression. Try escaping the curly braces with a backtick. ``logman create trace TestTrace -rt -p `{4027c655-f257-47ed-90f5-ecd6d2959e60`} -ets``

Comment: I am invoking this command which validates the Guid. Any alternative?

Comment: Why wont escaping the brackets work?

Comment: Its a parameter in Setting file. Which is verified as a Guid type. Which is then appended in the command by external system. It worked so far.

Comment: Thanks Matt. This will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue most likely lies in that powershell will try to interpret `{4027c655-f257-47ed-90f5-ecd6d2959e60}` as a script block. The value you intended to pass to `-p` would have been eaten up by the interpreter.

What you can do is escape the quotes with backticks so that it gets passed on properly.

```
logman create trace TestTrace -rt -p `{4027c655-f257-47ed-90f5-ecd6d2959e60`} -ets
```